# Neo4j plugin : can't use the spatial procedures after installing neo4j spatial plugin

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial, neo4j-plugin

So I have neo4j3.1.4 community edition, and tried to put neo4j spatial plugin jar v0.24 file under the "E:\softwares\Neo4j CE 3.2.0\plugins" directory. "E:\softwares\Neo4j CE 3.2.0\" is my neo4j installation directory. I couldn't find any of th procedures of spatial from cypher through browser. But I seem to have done exactly what the manual told me.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the installation path I'd say you actually have Neo4j 3.2.0 running, no ? Anyway (shouldn't make a difference really), if you take the latest release from https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial/releases/download/0.24-neo4j-3.1.1/neo4j-spatial-0.24-neo4j-3.1.1-server-plugin.jar, drop it into the plugins directory and then restart (don't forget that) Neo4j, things should work. You can verify if the spatial-procedures are there with a CALL dbms.procedures(). If not, please verify the neo4j.log file ... there are multiple messages about loading "geometry" related stuff in there if things go well (or you may see the reason it's not loading otherwise).

Also, and again judging from your installation directory, I think you may have used the Windows installer ? If so, the plugins directory is actually located at C:\Users\youruser\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\plugins, not in the installation directory.

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: Thank you, and pology for the simple mistake I made.BTW, Is there documents explaining those Neo4j spatial procedures in detail? I faliled to find any. It's hard to guess those parameter meaning without api docs.

Comment: You mean other than what is available at http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/spatial/ ? I notice there's a docs-directory if you check out the source of the project itself but I'm not sure that contains a lot more information.